# Use of the verb 'store'

Tags: word-usage

Can the verb 'store' be used as in the following sentence?

This drawer can store many objects.

My question is, is it okay to have a storage device as 'this drawer' as the subject of the verb? Or does the subject always have to be a person, as in 'I can store many things in this drawer.'

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds okay to me, as a non-native English speaker. I totally understand what the sentence means, but I don't know what the others think.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is perfectly fine. You used the modal verb "can" to talk about ability. The subject doesn't always have to be a person. I've found this sentence example on Google: '
In some cases, one or two drawers can hold all your make up.'

Comment: Would it be incorrect if I do not use 'can'? If I say, 'This drawer stores many objects.'

Comment: 'This drawer stores many objects' is also correct. It shows the condition of the drawer. I've found another sentence example that might help you 'the two-door cabinet stores loads of files and office equipment'